# Junit Error: initializationError(org.junit.runner.JUnitCommandLineParseResult)

Tags: java, unix, junit, terminal

I am new to **Junit** and am trying to run my program. I have already figured out how to compile it, but whenever I run it I keep getting this:

```
1) initializationError(org.junit.runner.JUnitCommandLineParseResult)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not find class [AnimalTester]
```

I am writing this to run:

```
java -cp junit-4.12.jar:hamcrest-core-1.3.jar:. org.junit.runner.JUnitCore AnimalTester
```

I am using terminal. I know that I can use eclipse, however, I am trying to figure out how I can do this without eclipse. Also, I have already done my research in trying to figure out this problem, but nothing seems to be working. I keep getting the same message.
Thank you for your help!

Comment: Try prefixing the class name with the package name.

Comment: @VHS I just have all my files in my src folder. I was trying to get my java files in my src and my class files in my classes folder, but I kept getting an error when I would direct the .class files in my command line. So, what do you mean by prefixing the class name?

Comment: He means adding this to your command line `...org.junit.runner.JUnitCore org.yourpackage.AnimalTester`

Comment: Depending on where you run `java` command, you need to specify the path of your class name including the package name.

Comment: @VHS okay so I have `home/JunitPractice/src` and then in my `src` I have `AnimalTester.class` `AnimalTester.java` `Cat.java.` `Cat.class` `Dog.java` and `Dog.class`. From the src directory I just tried doing this: `java -cp junit-4.12.jar:hamcrest-core-1.3.jar:. org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.AnimalTester` and it still didn't work. I am still getting an error saying "`Could not find or load main class org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.AnimalTester`"

Comment: prefixing the class name with the package name worked for me. Thanks @VHS

Comment: @UmangDesai, you are welcome.